# How can I split a String like [A,B,C] into A B C (Java)

Tags: java, string, list, split, brackets

For an input like `[A,B,C]` or something between commas and between brackets, how can I split the string to add it to a list?

I have this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String a = "[A,B,C]";
String str[] = a.split(",|\\[|\\]");
list = Arrays.asList(str);
System.out.println(list);
```

but the output is: `[, A, B, C]`

How can I split this string to add it to a list?
I want  list = `[A,B,C]`

Comment: can you give an example of an output?

Comment: I've edited with an example of the output.

Comment: That looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). How did you get `[A,B,C]` in the first place? What is your goal? If it is result of calling `toString()` method on some List and trying to convert String result back to a List then you should be using serialization and deserialization instead. If you want to do it in human-readable form you can use something like JSON.

Comment: You only have to remove the first and last bracket. So `String str[] = a.substring( 1, a.length() - 1 ).split( "," );` is sufficient and faster instead of the `replaceAll` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omit the brackets, it's faster than using `.replaceAll`:

```java
a = a.substring(1, a.length() - 1); // Substringing removes first and last character
String[] str = a.split(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution using Regular Expressions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String a = "[A,B,C]";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
    while(m.find()) {
        list.add(m.group());
    }

    System.out.println(list); //[A,B,C]
}
```

Match all letters from the input string and add them into the list one by one.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution can be to replace the brackets before splitting on comma.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String a = "[A,B,C]";
        String str[] = a.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split(",");
        list = Arrays.asList(str);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[A, B, C]
```

Comment: When an input like `[Something[Something]]` goes in, your code will return `["SomethingSomething"]` instead of `["Something[Something]"]`

Comment: @DelfikPro - You can think of `n` number of possibilities. This answer specifically solves the problem in the question.

Comment: `if (a.equals("[A,B,C]")) return new String[] {"A", "B", "C"};`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to just remove the brackets and split on a comma.  Then you can stream the array and enter into a list.

```
String s = "[AAAA,   BBBB ,  CCCCC,DDDDDD]";
List<String> list =
        Arrays.stream(s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","").split("\\s*,\\s*"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCCC
DDDDDD
```